# Retrieving Data from Firestore with angular/fire/rxjs

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire

I'm trying to get collection data from a firestore instance and don't want to use valueChanges{idField: id}. So far this is the only solution that somehow processes some of the data and gets the output close to what I need.

I'm  new to angular & angular/fire as well as to rxjs and am really struggling to understand observables, pipe, map and rxjs in general.

What am I missing here?

```
async fetchJobs() {
  let jc = await collection(this.firestore, 'jobs');
  let cSN = await collectionSnapshots(jc);
  let jobsArr = cSN.pipe(
    map((data) =>
      data.forEach((d) => {
        let jobsData = d['_document']['data']['value']['mapValue'][
          'fields'
        ] as Job;
        const newData = {
          id: d.id,
          title: jobsData.title,
          subtitle: jobsData.subtitle,
          description: jobsData.description,
          publish: jobsData.publish,
          img: jobsData.img,
        } as Job;
        return newData;
      })
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: What version of firebase are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your question and sorry, I didn't mention in my original post. I've just recently installed firebase, so I'm working with angular 14.0.1 and angular fire 7.4.1. I appreciate your input!

Comment: I see but are you using Firebase version 8 (namsespaced) or version 9 (modular)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. If I type "firebase --version" in the terminal it says 11.0.1 but in my package.json it says firebase": "^9.8.3".

Comment: OKay, cool then you are using Firebase modular.

Comment: Just to confirm you want to get data from Firestore collection?

Comment: Yes, hope I'm not confusing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
fetchJobs(): Observable<Job[]> {
   const jc = collection(this.firestore, 'jobs')
   return collectionSnapshots(jc)
   .pipe(
     map((snapshots) =>
      snapshots.map((snapshot) => {
        return { ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id } as Job
      })
     )
   )
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
fetchJobs(): Observable<Job[]> {
   const jc = collection(this.firestore, 'jobs')
   return collectionData(jc, { idField: 'id' })
   .pipe(
     map((data) => data as Job[])
   )
}
```

Since you only need to fetch the Job's data, `collectionData()` is **way more appropriate**.

`collectionSnapshots()` may be interesting when you need to perform additional operations on each Job, such as updating/deleting each one of them, which is possible with `snapshot.ref`

Example:

```
fetchJobs() {
   const jc = collection(this.firestore, 'jobs')
   return collectionSnapshots(jc)
}

deleteAllJobs() {
   fetchJobs()
   .pipe(take(1))
   .subscribe(snapshots =>
      snapshots.map((snapshot) => {
        deleteDoc(snapshot.ref)
      })
   )
}
```

This is a mere example and the logic may not apply to your use case.

Comment: If it works for you just tell me and I'll further detail my answer so you can better understand it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm! If you have any details and the time to share them, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure! Could you just first elaborate on why you wan't to use collectionSnapshots() as opposed to collectionData() with idField automatically set?

Comment: It’s a bit more capricious, no? I thought I would learn more that way. And the valueID field seemed more static to me but I might be mistaken.

Comment: If you only need the data, which is the most common use case in your front-end, consider using `collectionData`/`docData` which simplifies your data services. If you also use CloudFunctions (w/ Firestore Triggers), you commonly use snapshots as you can use their `ref` for additional operations.